# Dragablz tabablzcontrol

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, material-design, tabcontrol, material-design-in-xaml

How can I fix that problem?

I am using Dragablz tab controls in a WPF  project. If tab header's font size is too big, it will disappear. 
Need some padding? Margin?

[image]

Comment: Surprisingly, lolzlzl, there is actually something real called [Dragablz tabablzcontrol](https://dragablz.net).

Comment: Sounds like the controltemplate or something forces those to a fixed height. I'd look at modifying the template. I'd also look at using a font size that wasn't annoyingly large, and if that weren't an option, I might put a ScaleTransform on the whole tabcontrol.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I need to use large font size, since it is an app that runs at 1920x1080. I can't modify the style since I don't know where the code is.

Comment: Make a copy of the template. You can restyle and/or retemplate anything.

Comment: ohai, [teh coads heer](http://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz)

Comment: can you post the xaml?   Help us to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the Material Design theme for Dragablz is set according to the standard Material Design font size, you need to adjust the tab header item style to account for your larger font size.  Where you setup your Dragablz style (probably in your App.xaml), do this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabablzControlStyle}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="dragablz:DragablzItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDragableTabItemStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="120" />
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: It did work! Thanks so much.Just one little problem, it changed the background color to purple, like buttons I guess e___e

Comment: There are two styles. change  MaterialDesignTabablzControlStyle to MaterialDesignAlternateTabablzControlStyle to go back to white.